# HTTP Status 404 description The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, http

I am performing CRUD operations on MongoDB using SPRING REST api. But I am getting the following HTTP error:

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type: Status report

message

description: The requested resource is not available.
```

My start default page (basically a simple welcome page) is working fine but when I click on a link in my page to redirect me to another page (where i perform the crud operations) then it shows this error.

Here's my **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.manishchhabra.blog</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloSpringWithMongoDB</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>HelloSpringWithMongoDB Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>HelloSpringWithMongoDB</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Heres my **web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<display-name>Spring With MongoDB Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>
```

Here's my **dispatcher-servelet.xml** (WEB_INF/jsp/dispatcher-servelet.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.manishchhabra.blog" />

<!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="localhost" />
</bean>

<!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and querying the documents in the database -->
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
</bean>

<!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in 
    @Repository annotated classes -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />


<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

I am using Tomcat v7.0 to run this on local server. The link for the entire code is this:
[tutorial for the code](http://blog.manishchhabra.com/2013/04/spring-data-mongodb-example-with-spring-mvc-3-2/)

I have tried for days to remove this error. Kindly help me out.

**EDIT:** There are no errors being shown in the log. But for reference heres the log:

```
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/avarshney/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HelloSpringWithMongoDB' did not find a matching property.
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1367 ms
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 30, 2015 3:17:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5452 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your requested url?

I think your servlet-mapping part has some problem, you can change to:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer but now even the welcome page is showing the above error. The welcome url is : 'http://localhost:8081/HelloSpringWithMongoDB/' and the url where the CRUD operations will be performed is: 'http://localhost:8081/HelloSpringWithMongoDB/person' wherein /person/save is one operation

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing some jars (although no error was being reported) which on placing into the m2 repository solved the problem.